# Why does input value sent to firebase return empty?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase-realtime-database

This my code

```
btn.addEventListener("click", writeData);
 function writeData() {
  database.ref("todo" + item).set({
  item: document.getElementById("input").value
 });
}
```

There is no problem when I manually send string values but when I try to send the input value it returns empty. What should I do ? I'm new to firebase

[image]

Comment: Remove the parenthesis after `writeData` when you pass it to `addEventListener` (so `btn.addEventListener("click", writeData);`). You want to pass it as a reference, instead of executing it immediately and passing the return value.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Show the updated code in your question please.